# Sharepoint 2010 web part resize image to multiple sizes

Tags: web-part

Does anyone know of a Web Part for SharePoint 2010 that will allow you to upload an image and have it re-sized to multiple different sizes?

Comment: I don't, but I've done similar in custom code before. It's a pretty straight forward customization. I'd probably do it as an after event reciever on an image library.

Answer (score 1):

I would create a ashx handler, they go in the layouts folder. (This is also the normal way in aspx to resize images etc)

How to deploy ashx in sharepoint:

http://www.lifeonplanetgroove.com/2010/10/15/adding-and-deploying-generic-handlers-ashx-to-a-sharepoint-2010-visual-studio-project/

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6933258/how-to-make-jquery-ajax-request-with-a-http-handler-in-sharepoint-2010

Resizing images example:

http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2004/Feb/26/Creating-Thumbnail-Images-on-the-fly-with-ASPNet